# Distorting UITableViewCell when scrolling?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-graphics, core-animation

I try to make some special effects in an iOS App when user scrolls the `UITableView`. The effects I would like to implement is:

[image]

which is from [here](http://capptivate.co/2013/07/12/making-3/).

It is made by Capptivate, but I read through the website & I'm still confused where can I obtain the library.

I know Core Graphics / Core Animation / QuartzCore Framework may help, as hinted by this [tutorial](http://matt.coneybeare.me/how-to-make-custom-drawn-gradient-backgrounds/). So, assuming the effect is based on a `UITableView`, how can I distort the `UITableViewCell` like the screenshot above?

I can make curved table cell by:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 

    if (![cell.backgroundView isKindOfClass:[CustomCellBackground class]]) {
        CustomCellBackground * backgroundCell = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];
        cell.backgroundView = backgroundCell;
    }

    if (![cell.selectedBackgroundView isKindOfClass:[CustomCellBackground class]]) {
        CustomCellBackground * selectedBackgroundCell = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];
        selectedBackgroundCell.selected = YES;
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundCell;
    }

    NSString * entry;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        entry = self.thingsToLearn[indexPath.row];
        ((CustomCellBackground *) cell.backgroundView).lastCell = indexPath.row == self.thingsToLearn.count - 1;
        ((CustomCellBackground *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).lastCell = indexPath.row == self.thingsToLearn.count - 1;
    } else {
        entry = self.thingsLearned[indexPath.row];
        ((CustomCellBackground *)cell.backgroundView).lastCell = indexPath.row == self.thingsLearned.count - 1;
        ((CustomCellBackground *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).lastCell = indexPath.row == self.thingsLearned.count - 1;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = entry;
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    return cell;
}
```

but I have no clue how to make it responsive to scrolling.

**My Question is:** in short, how can I make curved `UITableViewCell` when scrolling?

---

There are more SO questions I read:

- [Animate a point of a Bezier curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793469/animate-a-point-of-a-bezier-curve)
- [How to move a view along a curved path in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839814/how-to-move-a-view-along-a-curved-path-in-ios)
- [iOS CoreGraphics: Draw arc, determine arc angles from intersecting chord theorem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277708/ios-coregraphics-draw-arc-determine-arc-angles-from-intersecting-chord-theorem)

and some tutorials:

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/33193/core-graphics-tutorial-arcs-and-paths
- http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-4

Note: I'm working on iOS 7+ only.

Comment: If you are working in a table with a fixed number of elements (like a menu) then I would go for subviews and then use Quartz to create paths with a Bezier curve controlled from the touchesMoved method, instead of using UITableView and UITableViewCells.  Keep in mind that at the end all you see in your app is pretty much a UIView or subclass of it.....e

Comment: Also, check this example of manipulating a Bezier curve in touchesMoved, I posted, and that may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720179/uibezierpath-manipulation-on-ios/22720507#22720507

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at this github library - https://github.com/brocoo/BRFlabbyTable